# Adding a navigation bar to tab view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift2, tabbarcontroller

Most of the tutorials that I came across are just showing a Navigation Controller and then a tableview controller, this works fine IF i am using only the tableview controller, but in mycase I am already using TabBar Controller and now I want to have a bar on top of the viewcontrollers , DOESN'T necessarily have to have a back button. But something that merges with the topbar (time, battery and carrier), right now I have this 
[image]

but when I run I get is this
[image]

[image]

how can I fix this, do take note I am quite new and trying my best.

EDIT 1:
Followed the comments advise, happy now, but no title. :(

[image]

Comment: Instead of wrapping your tabviewcontroller in a navigation controller, wrap every view controller inside a navigation controller and then add them (navigation controllers) to tab controller.

Comment: yeah you put the tab bar first, and Editor->embed navigation controller for each of the view controllers segued from the tab bar controller.

Comment: Thankyou guys, that works but how to add title? (see my update)

Comment: @AdilSoomro Please answer this so I can mark yours as an answer.

Comment: @JackyBoi added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of wrapping your `UITabBarController` in a navigation controller, wrap every view controller inside a navigation controller and then add them (navigation controllers) to tab controller.

Few tips:

- `self.tabBarController` inside wrapped child `UIViewControllers` will
  give you the tab reference.
- When you want to hide bottom bar when pushing next UIViewController, do `nextViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;` and then push it on the `self.navigationController` will hide the bottom tab bar,
  handy when required.
- You can use `UITabBar` and `UITabBarItem` appearance methods to customize the look of your tab bar from one place in the app.